# retry (or) retryWhen does not seem to work with hot flux

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to implement reactor core for my work. I am stuck with the retries that we need to perform in case of error. Below is my sample code before adding any error

```
FluxSink<String> mainSink;
// Create the fulx and get handle to Sink
Flux<String> mainFlux = Flux.create(sink -> {
   mainSink = sink;
}, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);
// Convert to Hot Flux
ConnectableFlux<String> hotFlux = mainFlux.publish();
// Two operations, add A and B to the input
hotFlux.flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> Mono.just(o + "A")))
       .flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> Mono.just(o + "B")))
       .log()
       .subscribe();
// Activate
hotFlux.connect();
// Publish messages to test
Thread.sleep(5000);
int pendingItems = 25;
while(pendingItems > 0) {
     System.out.println("Publishing " + pendingItems + " item");
     mainSink.next(String.valueOf(pendingItems));
     System.out.println("Published " + pendingItems + " item");
     pendingItems--;
}
```

When I do this. It works fine.

Coming to the error case, lets say the second operation (appending "A") fails for an item. I am trying to get the following behavior.

1. The part where I try to add "A" has to be retried 3 times before giving up
2. Also I would like to have the whole Flux retried 5 times before giving up

was wondering how I could achieve the same.

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
FluxSink<String> mainSink;
// Create the fulx and get handle to Sink
Flux<String> mainFlux = Flux.create(sink -> {
   mainSink = sink;
}, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);
// Convert to Hot Flux
ConnectableFlux<String> hotFlux = mainFlux.publish();
// Two operations, add A and B to the input
hotFlux.flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> {
                  System.out.println("Processing for adding A : " + o);
                  if(count.incrementAndGet() >= 25) {
                       throw new RuntimeException("More than 25th item.. Boom.. !!!");
                  } else {
                       return Mono.just(o + "A")));
                  }
            }).retry(5)
              .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("**** Inner Error"))
       ).flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> Mono.just(o + "B")))
       .log()
       .subscribe();
// Activate
hotFlux.connect();
// Publish messages to test
Thread.sleep(5000);
int pendingItems = 25;
while(pendingItems > 0) {
     System.out.println("Publishing " + pendingItems + " item");
     mainSink.next(String.valueOf(pendingItems));
     System.out.println("Published " + pendingItems + " item");
     pendingItems--;
}
```

When I add the retry(5) inside the first flatMap as shown above, it works fine where it retries the appending of A 5 times for the 25th guy coming in - which is evident from the logs

I am unable to achieve the complete flux retry (point (2) in my above requirement). I tried adding a .retry(3) after the second flux thinking that it would retry the whole flux. But it does not seem to be retrying. Can someone help with this?

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
FluxSink<String> mainSink;
// Create the fulx and get handle to Sink
Flux<String> mainFlux = Flux.create(sink -> {
   mainSink = sink;
}, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);
// Convert to Hot Flux
ConnectableFlux<String> hotFlux = mainFlux.publish();
// Two operations, add A and B to the input
hotFlux.flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> {
                  System.out.println("Processing for adding A : " + o);
                  if(count.incrementAndGet() >= 25) {
                       throw new RuntimeException("More than 25th item.. Boom.. !!!");
                  } else {
                       return Mono.just(o + "A")));
                  }
            }).retry(5)
              .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("**** Inner Error"))
       ).flatMap(o -> Mono.just(o).map(s -> Mono.just(o + "B")))
       .retry(3)
       .log()
       .subscribe();
// Activate
hotFlux.connect();
// Publish messages to test
Thread.sleep(5000);
int pendingItems = 25;
while(pendingItems > 0) {
     System.out.println("Publishing " + pendingItems + " item");
     mainSink.next(String.valueOf(pendingItems));
     System.out.println("Published " + pendingItems + " item");
     pendingItems--;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All forms of `retry` work by re-subscribing to the "retried" source. it works wonders with cold `Flux`, but a hot `Flux` is less adapted to that.

Here with `publish()` conversion, there's no guarantee for late subscribers: as the retry is considered a late subscriber it sees nothing, because the `publish` has been disconnected by the original finishing in error.

What you would need is a way to keep the last item (the one that might cause the exception) and replay it for new subscribers (or rather, for retry attempts).

Another issue is that you use `create` to acquire a `FluxSink` that you store externally, which is not a good approach.

The good news is that both problems can be solved in one go by using a `ReplayProcessor`: you correctly get a dedicated sink to manually push data, and in case of error `retry` will be able to get the error-triggering value out of the history and make another attempt:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ReplayProcessor<String> foo =
            ReplayProcessor.create(1);
    FluxSink<String> sink = foo.sink();

    foo.subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);

    AtomicInteger transientError = new AtomicInteger(5);
    foo.map(v -> "C".equals(v) && transientError.decrementAndGet() >= 0 ? v + (100 / 0) : v)
            .doOnError(e -> System.err.println("Error, should be retried: " + e))
            .retry(5)
            .subscribe(System.err::println, System.err::println);

    sink.next("A");
    sink.next("B");
    sink.next("C");
    sink.complete();
}
```

This prints:

```
A
B
Error, should be retried: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Error, should be retried: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Error, should be retried: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Error, should be retried: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Error, should be retried: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
A
C
B
C
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon. Looks like it will do the Job. Will try this shortly and will mark the solution as accepted